# How to set initial state on IBM Q?

Tags: quantum-state, ibm-q-experience

For my undergraduate final project I am working on a Quantum Inspired Genetic Algorithm.

For this I am using IBM Q real devices and I need to set a custom initial state on qubits. Using the statevector simulator this was possible, however **I am not sure how to do so on real quantum hardware**. For example I want to put qubit into state $|\psi\rangle = \sqrt{0.3}|0\rangle + \sqrt{0.7}|1\rangle$.

Comment: Hi! Were you using `qc.initialize()` before? This can still be run on the real devices

Comment: Hi, I used it for the statevector simulator, but didnt use it for the real quantum computer backend and see...

Comment: Did you have an issue with running it? I just tested and was able to

Comment: @met927 I'm really glad... Would you mind sharing the code with me... it will be very helpful....

Comment: Just note that quantum tomography is used for a quantum state measurement, not for qubits initialization.

Comment: You can run `qc.initialize([1,0], 0)` to initialize it into the |0> state, where the 1st param is the vector to use and the 2nd is the qubits to apply it to. The state you are describing isn't a valid quantum state, as a^2 + b^2 = 1

Comment: Thank you very much this truly helped me....

Comment: @met927 regarding the Tomography, according to Wiki it is mentioned as "Quantum tomography or quantum state tomography is the process of reconstructing the quantum state (density matrix) "... I thought reconstructing the state is the input which we gave... I got confused from that... Would you mind sharing a bit on this as well..

Comment: Reconstructing the state means working out what it is when we don't know. See the [what tomography is used for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tomography#What_quantum_state_tomography_is_used_for) section on wikipedia. The initialization is sort of the opposite to that, it is how we are constructing the state as we are making it what we want.

Comment: I understand that Adhisha is looking for method how to initialize state of qubit and I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much all of you for the support. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

To prepare an arbitrary single qubit state it is possible to use $\mathrm{U3}$ gate. The gate is defined by a matrix

$$
\mathrm{U3}(\theta, \phi, \lambda)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta/2) & -\mathrm{e}^{i\lambda}\sin(\theta/2) \\
\mathrm{e}^{i\phi}\sin(\theta/2) & \mathrm{e}^{i(\phi+\lambda)}\cos(\theta/2) 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

When then gate is applied on a qubit in state $|0\rangle$ (i.e. initial state of all qubits on IBM Q), it is transformed to state

$$
|\varphi_0\rangle = \cos(\theta/2)|0\rangle + \mathrm{e}^{i\phi}\sin(\theta/2)|1\rangle.
$$

Setting parameters $\theta$ and $\phi$ allows you to get any single qubit state you need.

In your case $|\psi\rangle = \sqrt{0.3}|0\rangle + \sqrt{0.7}|1\rangle$, so obviously $\phi = 0$.

Since $\cos(\theta/2) = \sqrt{0.3}$ parameter $\theta$ is given as

$$
\theta = 2 \arccos(\sqrt{0.3}) = 1.9823.
$$

*Note 1: In case $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real numbers, $\phi = 0$ always and you can apply $\mathrm{Ry}(\theta)$ gate (i.e. y-rotation) with same parameter $\theta$ instead because $\mathrm{Ry}(\theta) = \mathrm{U3}(\theta,0,0)$.*

*Note 2: To preare any multiqubit quantum state, a method introduced in [Transformation of quantum states using uniformly controlled rotations](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0407010) can be employed.*